# Get a products from bigcommerce store based on date?

Tags: bigcommerce

i would like to get some products in my Bigcommerce store based on date using api. So i have followed the following api code like this. But no luck

```
$filter = array('date_created' => 'Sat, 25 Jan 2014 16:43:15 +0000');//query filter

$products = Bigcommerce::getProducts($filter);

But in the same way following one is working good.

$filter = array('sku' => 'CST-120');//query filter

$products = Bigcommerce::getProducts($filter);
```

So please any help me how can i change the date variable would be better

Comment: I've never used Bigcommerce, but looking at their API page (https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products) seems liked you need to change 'date_created' to 'min_date_created' or even 'max_date_created'. Maybe try that.

Comment: Thanking you so much Mr.robnick.Parameter 'min_date_created' has been working good.